# How to design a Button with 2 colors and a hard border for the gradient

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-vectordrawable

So I was trying to design a Button with a hard border between 2 gradients just like this:

[image]

This could be simply done with a Constraint Layout, the problem is that the onfocused,onpressed ecc. state would need a lot of code implementation. That's not the right way for me.

I was trying it with a simple XML Gradient:

```
<shape android:shape="rectangle" >
<gradient
android:type="linear"
android:centerX="75%"
android:startColor="#FF2f333f"
android:centerColor="#FF2f333f"
android:endColor="#FF262933"
android:angle="0"/>
</shape>
<shape android:shape="rectangle" >
<gradient
android:type="radial"
android:centerX="50%"
android:centerY="50%"
android:startColor="#FF2f333f"
android:centerColor="#FF2f333f"
android:endColor="#FF262933"
android:gradientRadius="75"/>
</shape>
```

But this still gives me the soft border between the 2 colors. Is there any simple way to do this with a button?

Comment: use  icon at the button end by drawableEnd attribute

Comment: the icon isn't the problem, the color gradient is the problem